# Qt release doesn't show image

Tags: c++, qt, deployment

I’ve been working on qt for 4-5 months now. and I’ve managed to create my first app using qt. i wanted to deploy my app. it is weird every time i run it through Qt, the images always show up. but, when I run it through release folder ( myApp.exe ), the images won't show up.

I’ve found some guide about putting .dll file and something to do with qt plugins. but, I found it hard to understand. could somebody explain to me in a simple way about how to do it? or could someone give me an example of its implementation?

BTW, I’m using `QImage` and `QLabel` to show the images.

sorry for my English. I hope you guys understand the problem I’m facing.

Answer (score 1):

When deploying, you should place the dlls of plugins for image formats in a directory named `imageformats` alongside the application executable to show the images and icons.

- In Qt4 : `qjpeg4.dll`, `qsvg4.dll`, `qico4.dll`, ...
- In Qt5 : `qjpeg.dll`, `qsvg.dll`, `qico.dll`, ...

These files could be found in the Qt installation directory in `plugins/imageformats`. Just copy the necessary ones to the `imageformats` directory beside your application executable file.

Comment: i have. i placed it under the same folder. nothing happened. images still won't show up.

Comment: i'm using relative path to load my images. then, i changed to load images from my resource. still it didn't want to show up.